# Overriding the equals() method to allow for hetergenous Objects

Tags: java, overriding, equals, comparator

Below is selected code from one of 5 classes for this assignment.

Each class must have a equals() method that can compare an object of its class to an object of any and all of the 5 classes.

My strategy is to convert each object value to a double for the sake of precision.

As each Class extends Number each class has a doubleValue() method to utilize.

the code would not compile unless I typecasted x to RationalN before executing doubleValue()

but when executing the code it complains when a object of another class is compared as it can't be typecasted to that Class.

I where do I go from here?

```
        public class RationalN extends Number{
          private int numerator;
          private int denominator;

          public RationalN(int x, int y){
            if (y == 0){
              throw new ArithmeticException("cannot devide by zero");
            } else {
              this.numerator=x;
              this.denominator=y;
            }
          }

          public double doubleValue(){
            double value = (double)numerator/(double)denominator;
            return (double)value;
          }

          public boolean equals(Object x){
            if (((RationalN)x).doubleValue() == this.doubleValue()){
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return false;
          }
        }
```

Comment: what classes are you ready to accept as being valid arguments to the equals() function?

Comment: You want to make sure that `x` has the same class as `this`.  If `x` is not null and `x.getClass() == this.getClass()` then they're of the same class.  If your class is `final`, `instanceof` will work too.

Comment: Do the other classes extend `java.lang.Number` as well? What about the other abstract methods that the superclass `Number` requires to be implemented ?

Comment: Do think you meant to say `Overriding the equals() method`.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky: I believe we are only being tested on the 5 classes we create, but compatibility with String would be useful.

Comment: @Gevorg: Two of the classes directly extend Number, the rest are extensions of the first two classes.

Comment: How do you compare a number to a string?

Comment: @Gevorg: I have a toString() method in each Class as part of the assignment. If object x is a string I could compare to this.toString(). Although it is not explicit in the instructions,because of the inclusion of this method, I assume  it would be wise to include strings as viable Objects for equals().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I get from your post, you want to check in equals whether the numeric value represented by your object equals the numeric value of the argument object. Therefore, comparing the classes is **not** appropriate. Instead, your equals() method has too look something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
    if(this == x)
        return true;
    if(x == null)
        return false;
    if(!(x instanceof Number))
        return false;
    Number n = (Number)x;
    return (n.doubleValue() == this.doubleValue());
}
```

This, however, violates the equals() contract:
new RationalN(1, 1).equals(new Integer(1)) would return true, but new Integer(1).equals(new RationalN(1, 1)); wouldn't - the above equals() method violates symmetry. It would therefore be appropriate to introduce an abstract class implementing Number (say, MyNumber) which is extended **only** by your five classes and implements equals() in the above fashion (using instanceof MyNumber).

Answer (score 1):

edit: I just realized that number has `doubleValue()` as an abstract method in the Number class. Ok this is perfect. Just implement equals in all five classes like this. Alternatively if Number is not required as an abstract class, then read below to see that you can create your own abstract class that implements `equals()` and save duplicated code.

```
public boolean equals(Object x)
{
  if(x instanceof Number == false)
    return false;

  Number other = (Number) x;

  return other.doubleValue() == doubleValue();
}
```

The reason why you can't do what you are doing in your equals is because you are casting whatever you are trying to compare against to a RationalN class. When this is done to a class that is not a RationalN, this results in a ClassCastException.

Since all classes extend Number and `doubleValue()` is declared as a method available to Number, you can now cast those classes to Number (if they are an instance of Number) and then access the method from there.

I hope this makes sense. I encourage you to read up on interfaces and polymorphism.

edit: As an aside, if you are not required to extend Number, you can create an abstract class which has the abstract method `doubleValue()`, and then you can provide a concrete implementation of equals(that I provided above) in the abstract class. Then have all five of your classes extend the abstract class. They would each then implement their own version of `doubleValue()`, but would share the `equals()` defined in your abstract class, and thus eliminate copy/paste of the `equals()` into all five classes. This would be the ideal route if you did not have to extend Number.

Comment: I like this, however we are not permitted to utilize interfaces for the purposes of this assignment. Thanks!